# Grep separates results by spaces

Tags: scripts, grep

When using the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads

pdffiles=$(ls | grep .*\.pdf )
for pdf in $pdffiles
do
  echo $pdf
done
```

The printed result is the name of the files separated by one on each line. I would want the name of the file to be conserved on the same line as i want to run more commands inside the loop using those names. I have tried using the -Z flag. When using this xargs it works fine.

Print Example

```
Understand
Your
Data
and
Be
More
Productive.pdf
Regular
Expressions.pdf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of why not to parse the output of `ls`.

In fact, it's not grep that is separating the result by spaces - the command substitution `pdffiles=$(ls | grep .*\.pdf )` creates a single *string* which the subsequent `for pdf in $pdffiles` breaks up into space-delimited tokens.

Instead use a shell glob to construct an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads

shopt -s nullglob

pdffiles=( *.pdf )

for pdf in "${pdffiles[@]}"
do
  echo "$pdf"
done
```

See also

- [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: I have read the second link and found a glob to work perfectly. But i dont understand why doesnt it work with grep?(It seems to me that the regex part of grep and glob statements are pretty similar)

Comment: @BillyCase the issue is not really related to `grep` - you command substituion `pdffiles=$(ls | grep .*\.pdf )` creates a single *string* which the subsequent `for pdf in $pdffiles` breaks up into space-delimited tokens